# Using HLint.hs file in EclipseFP

Tags: haskell, eclipse-fp, hlint

Is it possible to use HLint.hs file to customize HLint messages in EclipseFP?

I tried adding a `HLint.hs` file in the project root containing:

```
import "hint" HLint.HLint

ignore "Use camelCase"
```

but it has no effect:

[image]

**Update:**

For HLint to pick up the changes in the `HLint.hs` file it is required to run `Cabal install dependencies` by right clicking on the project:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EclipseFP runs HLint passing the project folder as the working directory, so a HLint.hs file there will be taken into account. HLint only runs when needed, so after putting the HLint.hs file or modifying it you need to touch your source files so they get rebuilt again and HLint runs on them again.

Comment: I did made sure to change the files after placing the `HLint.hs` file in root but it is still not working. Could you please have a look at what I tried, maybe you can spot the problem: https://github.com/razvan-panda/EclipseFP-HTF-test-example The camel-case warnings should be ignored from the `LibTest.hs`. Thank you